Docker read files from network drive with unicode characters in name
I have a .net application which runs in a Linux Docker conatainer.
I have mounted a Windows folder via network share.
Some file names contain Unicode characters (Georgian letters in my case) and I am unavailable to read those files as I am getting an exception:
System.Exception: 'Could not find file '/data/TEST/ტესტ 2024-04-15 173605.png'.'

Of course this file exists on disk. I have checked the mounted folder from Docker desktop and from the shell, and those files are displayed with question marks.
I have also tested Directory.GetFiles(directory); and the same all files are with question marks.
I think there is problem in mounting network drive. Here is my code for it:
volumes:
  sapvolume:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: cifs
      o: "username=administrator2,password=1234,vers=3.0"
      device: "//10.132.10.101/Attachments_Folder"


Can you share the actual bytes in the file name, as exposed on both sides? I'm guessing some Microsoft genius decided to normalize things in a way which does not round-trip properly.

add ,iocharset=utf8 , change utf8 to your windows encoding,   add it  to  your connection string o: "username=administrator2,password=1234,vers=3.0"

iocharset=utf8 - worked!  I was trying it before too but I did'nt realize that docker-compose down did'nt remove volume as I have mounting volume in dokcer compose file. Now I removed volume manualy and recreated it and whoala it worked!
Thanks!
